# Connecting Lucidworks With Documentum

Tags: apache, solr, dql, documentum, lucidworks

I am building an enterprise search application in which i am using the lucidworks as a search engine and EMC Documentum as a back end technology for storing documents and meta Data.Currently i am using DQL to fire up queries and fetch data in intermediate scenario but i am looking for some other instruments to connect the two maybe third party connectors or anything else.Please Suggest me the possible ways to connect the lucidworks with documentum.

Answer (score 1):

LucidWorks offers a Connector that extracts content from documentum. So you can use LucidWorks Search as well to search for documentum content.

http://www.lucidworks.com/market_app/documentum-connector-for-lucidworks/

regards 
Markus